# What does the term "30% caloric restriction" mean?

Tags: diet

I've been reading about various diets, and I keep seeing this language:

```
XX% caloric restriction
```

What does that mean, in practical terms?

---

See [this wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calorie_restriction) article for some examples of the language in use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**XX% caloric restriction** means reducing your BMR *(Basal Metabolic Rate)* by the **XX%** amount. BMR is basically the minimum calories your body needs to maintain all its natural process. So, if you do nothing at all in a day, your body will burn the calories equivalent to your BMR. [This article](http://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Basal-Metabolic-Rate) details how you can calculate it. 
 
So if you're using a program that requires 30% calorie reduction and your BMR is 2000, your daily calorie intake has to be 1400. If you're active, the total calories your body uses will increase, which will lead to a higher calorie deficit. That's basically how weight-loss through dieting works. 
 
Hope this works.